# Синхронизация настроек в PhpStorm на разных компах

Tags: phpstorm, плагин, settings

Есть ли плагин для PhpStorm, с помощью которого можно синхронизировать настройки IDE на всех своих компах через инет? Не импорт / экспорт, а именно автоматическая  синхронизация. Ну или ручная. Изменил настройки, нажал кнопку, а потом на другом компе только подхватил эти настройки и готово.

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте плагин [Settings Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566?pr=idea). он доступен для установки через Settings (Preferences, если у Вас MacOSX) | Plugins, Install Jetbrains plugin...

Comment: А он по умолчанию уже установлен. Ввел его в поиск и увидел что он есть и включен. Спасибо, попробую)